# I want to move formatted literal string to normal string

Tags: c#, asp.net

All I want to do is moving a formatted values from asp literal to a string.

Eg:

```
<asp:literal id='test'> </asp:literal>
```

In .cs

```
test.Text = '<b tag>USA</b tag>';
String newTest = test.Text;
```

As of am getting 'USA' this value in the string newTest.
All I am trying to get is **USA**.

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to do; the 1st line of your `cs` file will set the text of the literal to '<b tag>USA</b tag>' which doesn't look like valid html syntax (you don't need the `tag`, just `<b>`). But then are you trying to get the same html value back into the `newTest` variable? Why would you do that from the Literal and not just code behind where you have access to that string anyway?

Comment: Exactly am using <b> only... here in Stackoverflow to mention it I put that way. Else Stackoverflow is formatting on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression:

```
const string input = "<b tag>USA</b tag>";
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"\>(?<country>.*)\<\/");
var country = match.Groups["country"].Value;
```

This will match anything inbetween `>` and `</`